# Should my unit tests also test third-party library/package features?

Tags: python, unit-testing, wtforms

I've just started using unit tests and I'm trying to figure out how comprehensive my tests should be.  One particular thing that comes up is when I use packages/libraries whose components are already subject to tests of their own.  Should I be carrying out similar tests on those components myself, or should I only be testing the features that I've added?

For example, suppose I am developing a web app in Python and I'm using [WTForms](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms) to validate input.  Should I be writing tests which e.g. check behaviour when an email input is invalid, or when a required field is empty, etc, even though WTForms already contains its own tests of this form?

My gut feeling is that this is a bit redundant, especially since I can always just run the WTForms test suite on any installation myself, but I'm not sure if it's some kind of no-no to just assume the tests are good.

Answer (score 1):

By *definition* the unit's test responsability is to control the behaviour of one single piece of code. So your responsability as a developper is to consistenly write unit test for what **you** (or your team) develop.

When you speak of testing WTForms, you normally have no reason to write unit tests for it. But it can make sense to write integration test to control that the way you use it in your context (your code context) gives the expected results. It can later smooth any upgrade of the external code, because you will first run your integrations tests that should warn you of any unexpected change.

You can use same framework for unit and integration test, but you should know in which castle each test lives and what part it controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trust your gut here. If you are confident in the tests that come with WTForms and don't need to change its behavior, you don't need to add more.

That being said, if you plan on updating a library your project is depending on, having tests against it *can* be beneficial. Testing the behavior you depend upon gives you certainty that your code is still valid. If these tests fail, you have an indication that the library's behavior changed; you will probably have to adapt your code. I have heard people refer to such tests as 'health checks/tests'.